# How to fix "TypeError: this.parameterTypes is not a function" in cucumber-js?

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cucumberjs

I am trying to use Cucumber.js but for some reason the snippet generation is broken. I am not sure if my setup is wrong or if there's a bug in cucumber-js itself.

I setup a simple test project https://github.com/cwansart/cucumber-js-test and ran `npx cucumber-js` which throws the following errors:

```
TypeError: this.parameterTypes is not a function
    at CucumberExpressionGenerator.createParameterTypeMatchers (/home/runner/work/cucumber-js-test/cucumber-js-test/node_modules/@cucumber/cucumber-expressions/dist/src/CucumberExpressionGenerator.js:110:41)
    at CucumberExpressionGenerator.generateExpressions (/home/runner/work/cucumber-js-test/cucumber-js-test/node_modules/@cucumber/cucumber-expressions/dist/src/CucumberExpressionGenerator.js:27:42)
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

See: https://github.com/cwansart/cucumber-js-test/runs/1854253039

I tried to find the issue in the cucumber code but have not been successful so far.

The tests work then I add the `then` block in the `features/support/steps.js` again.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong at all with what you're doing (thanks for the test repo btw, that helped), it's an issue with a new version of a dependency.

Here's the GitHub issue: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/1571

There'll be a patch version of cucumber-js coming soon to address this but in the meantime if you override the version of `@cucumber/cucumber-expressions` in your project to `11.0.0` (so it doesn't pick up 11.0.1) that should work around it.

**Update:** A patch has been released to revert the issue:

> we've just released cucumber-expressions version 11.0.2 which fixes a regression from 11.0.1. If you `npm update` [in your project] the problem should go away.

Answer (score 1):

Same error here as well. I fixed my problem by downgrading to [cucumber 6.0.5](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/tree/6.x).

I downgraded with the following command `yarn upgrade cucumber@6.0.5`

Comment: Okay great, I can confirm that. Then I guess there's a bug. I have not found an issue in Cucumber's issue tracker. I guess I'll submit one. Thanks!

Comment: Fix is on the way: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/pull/1572